# How do I convert a double backbox or pattress into a triple?

Tags: electrical, tile

I have a double backbox in my kitchen that currently houses the oven switch and an electrical socket. I need a double socket, so need to extend the backbox.

[image: switch and socket]

[image: behind the switch and socket]

As you can see, the tiler has very neatly tiled over the backbox.

What is the least disruptive way of converting the single socket to a double socket?

Am I correct in thinking that I should,

1. Cut out this backbox
2. Cut out enough space for another gang on the right
3. Install a single backbox on the left
4. Install a double backbox on the right

Is there any other way? For example, I know that [Single To Twin Socket Converters](https://amazon.co.uk/dp/B003R7GG6K/) exist, can these be installed vertically? A bit of a bodge perhaps, but would it be compliant with building regulations?

NB

- I have a Bosch GOP 18V-28 multitool.
- I live in England.
- I am happy to do my own electrical work.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid trying to remove the original box. Given that the existing box has cables entering from two directions, removing it without significant damage to either the cables or the wall is likely to be very difficult.

While I don't think there are any rules prohibiting mounting a socket sideways, It will certainly go against peoples expectations.

IMO you have two reasonable options here.

1. Install a new flush box (either single or double) for the new socket alongside the existing flush box and run a spur from the existing socket to the new one.
2. Mount a double surface box over the top of one side of the existing flush box and bring the wires into it through the back. If the wires won't reach then extend them with terminal block or wagos in the existing box.

Comment: Good shout on the double spur! This would leave this location with three sockets rather than one so that would be even better! Thanks!